# How to Archive Document in Java project (DMS)

Tags: java, pdf, javafx, doc, dms

i'm developing a DMS.
i'm currently working on the document management system aspect , like Managing PDFs and Docs;

> Now I want my application to be able to show all the existing PDF and
>   DOC  files on the computer in my application. so that they can be
>   opened when the user clicks  on them.

**i'm currently just focusing on PDFs And Docs**

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter;


public class SearchDocFiles {
    public static String[] EXTENSIONS = { "doc", "docx" };

    public Collection<File> searchFilesWithExtensions(final File directory, final String[] extensions) {
         return FileUtils.listFiles(directory,
                                    extensions,
                                    true);
     }


    public static void main(String... args) {


         Collection<File> documents = new SearchDocFiles().searchFilesWithExtensions(
                    new File("/path/to/document/folder"),
                    SearchDocFiles.EXTENSIONS);
            for (File document: documents) {
                System.out.println(document.getName() + " - " + document.length());
            }
        }
    }
```

this uses Apache Commons IO expectially FileUtil

Comment: Pamparanpa: thanks . would you please send the email ?

Comment: can i have an email address to contact you? gmail or whatever

Comment: suulisindiyaka@stoicteam.com

Comment: let me know if you have recieved it